# Update table from another table located remotely

Tags: mysql

I have two different schema in mysql both of them are installed in two different servers lets say a and b, if a table in "b" server gets inserted or updated it should be reflected in "a" server also.

Comment: answer can be in java also, it's better to be in mysql :)

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication.html

Comment: i can't change the server configuration at client side.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have replication setup, you will definitely have to do this on the application level, i'm not sure how else 2 mysql servers will communicate with each other without the proper configuration. You're going to have roll your own Java solution for this one where you do it on per change basis or you will have to periodically sync the data on both servers.